# The name of the sum $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{m-i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, terminology, fractions, harmonic-numbers

Sorry for the vague question name, since I am looking for the name of the series.
Also this might not be a "series" by the strict definition of a series.. anyways here it is:

Choose some $m$ and $n$ as some positive integer, and $m> n$.
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{m-i}$$

Comment: Offset harmonic numbers?

Comment: It's the difference of two harmonic numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, my question looks much nicer.

Comment: You could also write $\sum\limits_{i=m-n}^m \frac{1}{i}$.

Comment: @Kundor Ah that's clever, so it's just a harmonic series with odd limits.

Comment: This is not a different series than finite harmonic series , since it can be written as difference of two harmonic series with different uppper index or just one harmonic series with lower index starting at higher number,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Kundor stated above, this is a harmonic sum with strange bounds. (like you stated)